# How to automate testing of different versions of jars?

Tags: java, unit-testing, gradle, jar

I would like to automate testing of different versions of library working in the same project.

Is it possible?

Can I change versions in Gradle and run tests against each combination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass a version on command line

```
gradle build -PfooVersion=1.0 -barVersion=2.0
```

Then in your gradle script

```
dependencies {
    compile "x:foo:${fooVersion}"
    compile "y:bar:${barVersion}"
}
```

Then you could script the running of the various combinations you want to run

Note: There's a [GradleBuild](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/GradleBuild.html) task which can execute another gradle build so you could have one gradle build execute another multiple times with the different parameter combinations. Eg:

```
apply plugin: 'base'

def allFooVersions = ['1.0', '2.0', 3.0']
def allBarVersions = ['1.1', '2.2']

[allFooVersions, allBarVersions].eachCombination { combination ->
    // create a task for each combination
    GradleBuild task = tasks.create("combination${combination}", GradleBuild)
    task.buildFile = 'path/to/build.gradle'
    task.startParameter.projectProperties = [
        fooVersion: combination[0], 
        barVersion: combination[1]
    ]
    task.tasks = ['test']

    // wire the task into the dag
    check.dependsOn task
}
```

Comment: This code should be in the same `build.gradle` or in different?

Comment: Sorry, don't understand a word in your script :)

Comment: It's two separate build scripts. One accepts versions as parameters and uses the parameters for dependency versions. The other is a harness which executes the first using all version combinations.

Comment: I put combinations script into separate file of `combinations.gradle` and was able to run it with `gradle --continue -b combinations.gradle check`. Thanks! Now I woould like to know, how to gather results :)

Answer (score 0):

You could have different branches in your SCM with different dependency versions defined in gradle build file each.

Then you cold have a build server that rebases each testing branch  ob top of your dev branch and runs the tests.